About old rotary phones and Asterisk
Asterisk (at least on version 17) support old rotary phones without problems (with option pulsedial=yes ). I have tested with success three rotary phones.
My phone company support pulsedial (is the only one in my country as I know), even in fttc (ftth not tested).
My fast question is this: if one day, the ftth arrive in my city, or the company phone drop the pulsedial/rotary support, it will possible to use those phones in asterisk?
I explain better
The situation now (working)
---> = connected to


rotaryphone---->Asterisk---->VOIPROUTER--->FTTCROTARYSUPPORTED

The situation in the future
rotaryphone---->Asterisk---->VOIPROUTER--->FTTH?

Consider asterisk is connected to voiprouter as a "ip phone" so it use the sip protocol.

The question maybe belongs on the Network Engineering Stack Exchange, for sure not on Super User. But the answer is that the type of internet used for SIP/VoIP does not matter whatsoever, FTTH and FTTC are all the same network

If you are using VOIP then any "interpretation" of pulse dialing is done prior to the call going onto the internet. In which case, phone company support of pulse dialing is irrelevant.

You can buy pulse-to-tone converters for US$25 to US$40 or so, e.g., https://www.aliexpress.us/w/wholesale-rotary-dial-pulse-tone-converter.html, https://www.amazon.com/s?k=rotary+dial+pulse+tone+converter . That still won't provide missing * and # keys...
